# Which is grammatically correct: He and I was or he and i were?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

which is correct between following two sentences:
1. He and I was going to temple.
or
2. He and I were going to temple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is the correct one.

Comment: Really??? Have 99% of people writing English books in the past two centuries got it ***wrong***? [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+and+I+was%2CHe+and+I+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20and%20I%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20and%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, should be the second answer.